# How can I rotate these offsets by an angle?

Tags: canvas, d3.js, html5-canvas, 2d, processing

I am arranging circles in an equal distribution in a circular 'orbit' around a center point with the following math, where k is the index of the circle within its collection, n is the total number of circles in the collection, r is the distance from the center point, and x and y is the center point itself:

```
left = x + r * cos(2*k*PI/n)
top = y + r * sin(2*k*PI/n)
```

I'm sort of trial-and-erroring my way through this, and am attempting to now animate these circles by applying a rotation angle and incrementing the angle with a timer to animate. If I have my angle in radians, **how might I modify the above equations to apply said rotation transform**?

Comment: can you put this up on a working fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to set a new variable, let's call it `myRotation` and add it to your angle so each circle will keep moving the same amount of radians.

```
left = x + r * cos(2*k*PI/n+myRotation)
top = y + r * sin(2*k*PI/n+myRotation)
```

Just keep increasing `myRotation` and redraw the circles. See example below

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 500;
c.height = 500;

var x = c.width/2;
var y = c.height/2;

var n = 8; //number of circles
var r = 100; // radius of large circle, along which all small circles travel
var myRotation=0;

function drawCircles() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    for (var k=0; k<n; k++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x+r*Math.cos(2*k*Math.PI/n+myRotation),y+r*Math.sin(2*k*Math.PI/n+myRotation),20,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    myRotation+=0.005;
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCircles);
}

drawCircles();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already said this a few times in my answer, but always remember that, with the Context2D, **you don't have to do the math** if you don't want to (or if you don't know).

The transforms ( `translate`, `rotate`, `scale`) allows you to consider the canvas as a sheet of paper that you can move, rotate, zoom in/out with those functions, then you just have to wonder where to put your pen, where to go from there, and lastly to fill/stroke.

You shouldn't hesitate to build small drawing functions to build your draw, to promote re-use, easy debugging, and easy changes.

In your example, let's just draw the planets, first.

```js
function drawPlanets(context, centerX, centerY, orbitDistance, planetCount) {
  context.save(); // save the context before any transform.
  context.translate(centerX, centerY); // move to the center
  var angle = 2 * Math.PI / planetCount; // angle between two planets
  for (var i = 0; i < planetCount; i++) {
    drawPlanet(context, orbitDistance);
    context.rotate(angle);
  }
  context.restore(); // restore to previous state
}

// draw a planet in the current context, that is centered
// and already oriented towards the planet.
function drawPlanet(context, distance) {
  drawCircle(context, distance, 0, planetsRadius);
}

function drawCircle(context, x, y, radius, fill) {
  context.fillStyle = fill || '#ADB';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

var sunRadius = 80;
var planetsOrbit = 160;
var planetsRadius = 20;
var planetCount = 8;
var sunPosition = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200
};

// boilerPlate
var context = cv.getContext('2d');

drawPlanets(context, sunPosition.x, sunPosition.y, planetsOrbit, planetCount);
```

```html
<canvas id='cv' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Now to build an animation, you just have to rotate the whole context before drawing the planets by a growing amount, that's all :

```js
function drawPlanets(context, centerX, centerY, orbitDistance, planetCount, angleShift) {
  context.save(); // save the context before any transform.
  context.translate(centerX, centerY); // move to the center
  // !!!! Only change is here !!!!
  context.rotate(angleShift || 0 );
  var angle = 2 * Math.PI / planetCount; // angle between two planets
  for (var i = 0; i < planetCount; i++) {
    drawPlanet(context, orbitDistance);
    context.rotate(angle);
  }
  context.restore(); // restore to previous state
}

// draw a planet in the current context, that is centered
// and already oriented towards the planet.
function drawPlanet(context, distance) {
  drawCircle(context, distance, 0, planetsRadius);
}

function drawCircle(context, x, y, radius, fill) {
  context.fillStyle = fill || '#ADB';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

function drawScene() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
  drawPlanets(context, sunPosition.x, sunPosition.y, planetsOrbit, planetCount,  (Date.now()  - startTime ) / 1000);
}

var sunRadius = 80;
var planetsOrbit = 160;
var planetsRadius = 20;
var planetCount = 8;
var sunPosition = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200
};

// boilerPlate
var context = cv.getContext('2d');
var startTime = Date.now();

setInterval( drawScene, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id='cv' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```